# Comparing data/running a "difference report" on data in same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called "items"

```
id       month       year       **itemname**       distmoney
 1        12         2012         chicken           20
 2        12         2012         pork              15
 3        11         2012         chicken           21
 4        11         2012         pork              15
```

I am trying to run a "difference report" on items with the same name.

So for chicken, it is found in month 12 & 11. If distmoney is different for these two months, i want to echo a warning or something of that nature. In my example above, distmoney for chicken is 20 for month 12 but 21 for month 11. So, a "warning!" should be echoed. For pork, however, distmoney remains the same so I would just echo "no issues" or something of the sort.

How can I go about doing this?

Thanks for any help. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY` the rows on the `itemname` column and see how many distinct values are in `distmoney` column. If there are more than one distinct value, then there may be a problem.

```
SELECT 
    name,
    IF(COUNT(DISTINCT distmoney) > 1, 'warning!', 'no issues') AS status
FROM
    items
GROUP BY
    name
```